# Setting a child div's width to 100% when parent has set width

Tags: html, css

My question is, I have a parent div that is set at 712px wide. Inside of that I need a carousel that is 100% width (the width of the window). Below that carousel, I need the footer.

The issue is that footer is under the carousel. How can I make the carousel take up a dynamic height so the footer appears below it instead of under it?

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    This is some content above the carousel.
    <div id="carousel">Some stuff in here that needs to be 100% width.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    The footer
  </div>
</div>

#wrapper {
    width:712px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#eee;
}

#carousel {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yJ4EM/

Thank you!

Comment: borders count for width calculations, so your carousel is actually `100% + 2px` wide, making it wider than the wrapper.

Comment: border can be removed, it was just there for visual guide.

Comment: it is not clear what you're trying to achieve in terms of heights, do you want the footer sticked at the bottom of the screen? how should the carousel's height behave?

Comment: You've also made your carousel be positioned absolutely, which means it no longer counts for document flow calculations. e.g. it's now acting more like a paper note you've taped to the front of your monitor, rather than as part of the document.

Comment: Carousel's height is dynamic.

Comment: Footer needs to appear after the carousel content. Not fixed to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Carousel position should be set to **relative**.

Comment: setting the carousel's position to relative causes it to inherit the wrappers width, thus not making it 100% wide (width of the window).